# Extracting Images from the external website

Tags: image, web, external

Can anyone explain me what is been used on this template to secure the images used in the website template http://template-entitled.webflow.com/ and is there anyway I can extract them out, every time I save the pages, I just able to save icons not the background and slider images. I downloaded its css and js files but couldn't find and png files for background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you just need the background images or you need to recreate the same effect of this theme. Anyway if you just need the images with firefox you can right click on the image an choose visualize background image (not sure if the English menu is exactly like this) and you'll have the url of the image (i.e.: http://uploads.webflow.com/533e797fc51278ef4200094a/534e45fb2dd7fcb8350002df_Office-6-2.jpg)